# Creating a list of the minimum values of a nested list by index

Tags: python, list, min, nested-lists

I have a series of nested lists of the same length (the number of lists varies):

```
list1=[[5.5,4,6.21,3.4,8.1,3.8],[3.8,2.1,5.1,4,12.3,2.4],[4,2.11,8.2,3.6,4.5,2]]
```

I'm trying to create a list of the smallest number per index of each list, i.e.

```
list2=[3.8,2.1,5.1,3.4,4.5,2]
```

Really unsure of where to start, other than the answer being either a list comprehension or for loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` with `min` + `zip`:

```
res = list(map(min, zip(*list1)))
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension:

```
res = [min(i) for i in zip(*L)]
```

For larger lists, performance is comparable between these methods:

```
L = list1*100000

%timeit list(map(min, zip(*L)))    # 110 ms per loop
%timeit [min(i) for i in zip(*L)]  # 123 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy's min function

```
import numpy as np
list2 = np.min(list1,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted more generic solution using `for` loops. Another answers are better in production env, but it maybe more educational for some:

```
list=[[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,1],[4,5,1,6]]
result = list[0]
for i in range(1, len(list)):
  for j in range(0, len(list[1])):
    if list[i][j] < result[j]:
      result[j] = list[i][j]

print(result)
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit (after sorting out my confusion);

```
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1[0])):
    list2.append(min([list1[j][i] for j in range(len(list1))]))
```

Try:

```
list2 = [min(i) for i in list1]
```

Where `min(i)` returns the lowest value in `i`, which in this case is a list. 
In `for loop` terms:

```
list2 = []
for sublist in list1:
    list2.append(min(sublist))
```

You could even individually calculate the smallest value using an implementation of the `min()` function, but since its there, I'll use that.

```
list2 = []
for sub in list1:
    lowest = sub[0]
    for item in sub:
        if item < lowest:
            lowest = item
    list2.append(lowest)
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants, see the expected output.

Comment: Almost - this returns [3.4,2.1,2], which are the minimum values for each list. I need the minimum value per index of the lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "per index"?